Possible to split word into char list in the C preprocessor
I have a preprocessor macro, called INSTR(...). It takes in a comma separated list of chars, and outputs a compile time constant number depending on the input. This macro currently works, and can be used like this:
enum Instructions
{
    INSTRUCTION_1 = INSTR('i','n','s','t','r','_','1'), //2408996205L when evaluated
    INSTRUCTION_2 = INSTR('i','n','s','t','r','_','2')  //2408996172L when evaluated
};

This currently works as intended, but obviously looks a bit clunky. I was wondering if it is possible to turn a word (not necessarily a string literal) in the preprocessor, turn it into a list of characters like that and insert it into the INSTR(...) function at compile time?
I've tried using string literals like mentioned here but it won't work at compile time.

I don't think so. There's an operator for concatenating tokens, but nothing for splitting them up.

I understand that it isn't your plan, but your INSTRUCTION_x could be a simple running number used to index an array of the numerical instructions, that you might populate in the runtime based on strings whatsoever.

could you add the source code for the INSTRC() macro? I'm curios as to how it transforms the list of characters into the actual numeric value. Also is there only a fixed number of these transformations that are valid? A bit more background as to what you are trying to accomplish with this specific approach would be helpful. I don't know of any Preprocessor operators for splitting a string however there may be another approach.

At compile time, you can preprocess source code using any program you want and then feed that program’s output to the compiler. Do not try to abuse the C preprocessor features to do fancy calculations. Just write your own program to prepare the values you want, document it well, and insert it into your build process.

@RichardChambers Sure, it's a compile time hash function (not cryptographic or secure) for turning text into enums

Not possible.  ^

GNU m4 is a very popular choice

@Dúthomhas Do you know how I'd achieve this with M4? I've been struggling to get the patsubst macro working with what I want

For cases like this, I always go with an external tool. Some script (usually perl) which takes a text file with key=value pairs and produces .h file with enums/defines from it. Add this .h generator into makefile and problem is solved.

Would it help to define a macro such as #define INSTR_INSTR_1 'i','n','s','t','r','_','1' and just the macro name? Are you only using these strings in this one place and are interested due to esthetic concerns for this particular area or are you using these strings in multiple places?

@RichardChambers It's only aesthetic really, so I could do that

I do not know how to use m4. But I am also of the opinion that there is a point of diminishing returns. How much time and energy and resources are you really willing to put into this one small problem? Just do it the simple but ugly way.

I do not feel that writing an answer at this time would add anything. Bottom line, the answer depends on what exactly does INSTR do with the argument. Is this a constant list of values, or is there an actual constant expression calculation that transforms the argument into the value? And bottom line, why not just hardcode it INSTRUCTION_1 = 2408996205L, // instr_1?
